# Problems with fs.readFileSync

Tags: node.js, windows

I'm trying to use node to use the photoshop api, I am currently trying to make a code based on the example of text edit, but, I can't deal with the fs.readFileSync, I need to use this to  to configurate my private key, for that, I need to put the path to my key, but It says "module bot found"

```
fs.readFileSync("C:\Users\jpcam\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\psdTeste\private.key"),
```

I don't know what I can do to this work

Can anyone help me?

I ve tried using also only the file name of the key, because the Kay and the code are in the same folder

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, the backslash is used as the escape character. For example, `\n` makes a newline character.

If you do `console.log("C:\Users\jpcam\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\psdTeste\private.key")` you'll notice that the result is `C:UsersjpcamOneDriveÁrea de TrabalhopsdTesteprivate.key`.

[Escape the escape character](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#escape_sequences) to get a backslash:

```
fs.readFileSync("C:\\Users\\jpcam\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\psdTeste\\private.key");
```

Alternatively, you can use [`String.raw()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) with a [tagged template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates) string:

```
fs.readFileSync(String.raw`C:\Users\jpcam\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\psdTeste\private.key`);
```

*Template literal strings use backticks, not single quotes*.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the key file and your script file are in the same folder and try this

```js
fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,"private.key"))
```